# Why do not some questions need reviewing any more (In triage)

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

When reviewing my past review history, I noticed that for some questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9409137))
apparently the reviewing process is suppressed (it is indicated that *This item is no longer reviewable*.) I'm wondering why?

another examples:

- [2:Unsalvageable,1:require editing,1:looks ok](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9614316)
- [1:Unsalvageable,0:require editing,1:looks ok](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9614405)
- [2:Unsalvageable,1:require editing,2:looks ok](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9614407)
- [1:Unsalvageable,0:require editing,2:looks ok](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9614413)

Comment: Just guessing but it could be because it was answered.  The first answer came 6 minutes after it was posted.  It could also be that there is accepted answer.  The accepted answer was accepted at 4:27 Zulu

Comment: @NathanOliver: The additional examples show that that's not a reliable indicator. Upvotes (and downvotes) are also not plausible, and none of the recent examples are closed yet; first outside-the-queue close-vote, maybe?